# Error -XQE-PLN-0229 in Cognos Framework Manager

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

I am getting below error while running report which uses factless fact from Framwork Manager:

> Error -XQE-PLN-0229 This query is not supported, because it only
>   contains dimension items and there is no single fact stream that
>   covers all of the entities. Resolve this issue by adding one or more
>   fact items to the query. RSV-SRV-0042 Trace back

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query planner obviously thinks there are no facts in the query.

What is the usage of the fact-less fact that you have in the query?

One way of approaching the problem could be to read through the error message and see whether what it thinks is a problem is the actual state of affairs.

"...because it only contains dimension items"
Is this true?

"and there is no single fact stream that covers all of the entities. "
Is this true?

"Resolve this issue by adding one or more fact items to the query." 
Make sure there's at least one query item which has a usage of fact in the query.

If there is, it could be that the fact-less fact is in the wrong position relative to the cardinalities of the relationships of the other query subjects.   Keep in mind not to change the cardinalities which accurately represent the relationships between objects in the different tables just to make a query work.

Answer (score 1):

check out the following link
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21698612

You might be able to remove the issue by creating a conforming dimension to allow outer joins and a coalesce (stitching) to handle this